# Is bean method with ListenableFuture return value executed in separate thread?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, asynchronous

Application declares interface for sending notifications with single method with `ListenableFuture<>` return type.

For mail service I *don't see exceptions* in case of misconfiguration (for example if SMTP server is down or host is not resolved) in my batch job.

Debugging shows that on:

```
MailNotificationService mailService = applicationContext.getBean(MailNotificationService.class);
```

I receive proxy that on method invocation:

```
mailService.send(mime);
```

resolved with stack:

```
  at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.invoke(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:101)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
```

Documentation for `invoke` says:

```
 * Intercept the given method invocation, submit the actual calling of the method to
 * the correct task executor and return immediately to the caller.
```

After some steps I see new thread `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1` and service executed here.

It looks like service executed in separate thread and exception doesn't propagated to original thread (if it is meaningful at all).

*Is it correct that for bean methods with `ListenableFuture<>` return type Spring execute them in separate thread?*

**NB** My original issue in that I am blind in case of errors in notification service (traces are not logged). Mail service throws unchecked `org.springframework.mail.MailException` and the only way to find that out is to wrap `.send()` method by `Exception` with logging:

```
@Autowired
private JavaMailSender mailSender;

public void notify() {
    try {
        mailSender.send(mime);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.warn("Can't deliver mail", ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/ - take a look here, I suppose method is @Async annotated, and async is enabled

Comment: **@white** Thanks! I didn't notice `@Async` annotation on service method and `@EnableAsync` on configuration class. Spring became monstrous.

Answer (score 1):

As **white** predicted I have @Async annotation on service method and @EnableAsync on configuration class.

Exception handling described in section:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#scheduling-annotation-support-exception

In case of `Future` return type (`ListenableFuture` is subtype of it) exception propagated to future object and can be retrieved from exception `ExecutionException.getCause()` which occur on `Future.get()` method call.

In my case I ignore return type (don't call `.get()`). So exception was not captured and logged. As I wrote originally excpetion logging should be done in task itself in this case.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutionException.html